filling an empty data frame or array with values from the column of another data frame if some conditions are met pandas
I need to creat an empty data frame that stores values from a column of another data frame base on some conditions being met in two columns of the same second data frame.
I have a data frame
test_mob_df = pd.DataFrame( {"geoid_o": [10002, 18039, 18039, 18182, 10006, 18111, 18005, 17001], "geoid_d": [10005, 18039, 18111, 18182, 18005, 17004, 18050, 15001], "pop_flows": [20,10,9,15,2,1,6,30]})
and a list of ids that I am interested in as state_county_fip = [18182, 18111, 18005, 18039, 18050, 18001]. I now need to create a new $nxn$ data frame (or an array) with row and column names as sorted state_county_fips, that stores the values in the pop_flows column of $test_mob_df$ whenever values in the same row of columns geoid_o and geoid_d match or not. In essence, the resulting data frame should look like this:




18005
18039
18005
18050
18111
18182




18005
0
0
0
0
0
0


18039
0
10
0
0
9
0


18005
0
0
0
6
0
0


18050
0
0
0
0
0
0


18111
0
0
0
0
0
0


18182
0
0
0
0
0
15



That is, I need to create a a dataframe (or matrix) of population flows from geoid_o to geoid_d, and when we do not have population flow from geoid_o to geoid_d, then we asign zero to the corresponding cell. For instance, 10 individuals moved from geoid_o 18005 to geoid_d 18050.
I can't seem to figure out how to do this beyond using query to create a data frame (from test_mob_df) that has the geoids of interest: data_counties_of_interest = test_mob_df.query("18001<=geoid_o<18200 and 18001<=geoid_d<18200"). I will deeply appreciate any help you can offer.

You can do:
test_mob_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "geoid_o": [10002, 18039, 18039, 18182, 10006, 18111, 18005, 17001],
        "geoid_d": [10005, 18039, 18111, 18182, 18005, 17004, 18050, 15001],
        "pop_flows": [20, 10, 9, 15, 2, 1, 6, 30],
    }
)

state_county_fip = [18182, 18111, 18005, 18039, 18050, 18001]

out = pd.crosstab(
    test_mob_df.loc[test_mob_df["geoid_o"].isin(state_county_fip), "geoid_o"],
    test_mob_df.loc[test_mob_df["geoid_d"].isin(state_county_fip), "geoid_d"],
    values=test_mob_df["pop_flows"],
    aggfunc="first",
)

out = (
    out.reindex(index=state_county_fip, columns=state_county_fip)
    .fillna(0)
    .sort_index(axis=1)
    .sort_index()
    .astype(int)
)

print(out)

Prints:
geoid_d  18001  18005  18039  18050  18111  18182
geoid_o                                          
18001        0      0      0      0      0      0
18005        0      0      0      6      0      0
18039        0      0     10      0      9      0
18050        0      0      0      0      0      0
18111        0      0      0      0      0      0
18182        0      0      0      0      0     15


Thanks for your solution. It does work and gives the exact output I expected. I am interested on its performance when used on a large data set.

@AkunwexOrwa Performance should be OK - depends how big is your dataset and the state_county_fip list. But I filter the values before doing crosstab, so the main bulk of operation should be in .isin() function.

Thank you very much for your insight. I upvoted your answer already. I am tone between your answer and that of @Onyambu. To help me decide on which one to accept, I will test them on my data frame and see their performance. Both of the solutions are excellent. How I wish it was possible to accept two or more answers.

@AkunwexOrwa Test is and accept the one which is faster :)

(test_mob_df[['geoid_o', 'geoid_d']]
  .apply(pd.Categorical, categories = sorted(state_county_fip))
  .assign(p = test_mob_df['pop_flows'])
  .pivot_table('p', 'geoid_o', 'geoid_d', fill_value=0, dropna = False))

geoid_d  18001  18005  18039  18050  18111  18182
geoid_o                                          
18001        0      0      0      0      0      0
18005        0      0      0      6      0      0
18039        0      0     10      0      9      0
18050        0      0      0      0      0      0
18111        0      0      0      0      0      0
18182        0      0      0      0      0     15


Thank you very much for your solution. It works like a charm. I have upvoted your answer, and I should accept it as the answer I was looking for. Before I do that, I just wanted to ask your opinion on the performance of this code when used on a data frame with more than 500,000 rows.
